# how to find googleplay id from this text?

Tags: php, preg-match

how to find googleplay id from this text with php? it is after Google ID:

Short Name: Coin Dozer – World Tour Google ID: com.gamecircus.CoinDozerWorld Version: 3.6 File size: 19.31 MB Category: Games, Casino

this is example code but not completed

```
 $file = "Short Name: Coin Dozer – World Tour Google ID: com.gamecircus.CoinDozerWorld Version: 3.6 File size: 19.31 MB Category: Games, Casino";
    preg_match("/Google ID: (.*)\s/", $file, $match)
```

Comment: Did you tried to solve this by yourself ?

Comment: use regular expression

Comment: yes , with preg_match but not work , i'm newbie

Comment: preg_match($sPattern,$sText,$aMatch);  i need help in pattern

Comment: No it's not bold or italic.

Comment: i updated code . look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to capture anything after `Google ID:` that isn't a space (assuming the googleplayid cannot contain a space).

```
/Google ID: ([^ ]+)/
```

https://regex101.com/r/lD8qB6/1

```
<?php
 $file = "Short Name: Coin Dozer – World Tour Google ID: com.gamecircus.CoinDozerWorld Version: 3.6 File size: 19.31 MB Category: Games, Casino";

preg_match("/Google ID: ([^ ]+)/i", $file, $match);

print_r($match); 
/**
 Array
  (
     [0] => Google ID: com.gamecircus.CoinDozerWorld
     [1] => com.gamecircus.CoinDozerWorld
  )
*/
```

https://eval.in/299290

Comment: Great, thank you ,how can i learn regular expression like you?

Comment: You're welcome. Start with http://www.regular-expressions.info/ then you can use sandbox sites like http://regex101.com and experiment. You can also learn by looking at the [regex tag](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/regex) and see the questions and answers and learn from those.